# Put Cursor after two lines in body part of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using  cursor in my `MFMailComposeViewController` body part with

```
- (BOOL) setMFMailFieldAsFirstResponder:(UIView*)view mfMailField:(NSString*)field{

for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    
    

    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [subview class]];
    NSLog(@"SubView -- %@ --- %@",className,field);
    
    if ([className isEqualToString:field])
        
    {
        
        //Found the sub view we need to set as first responder
        
        [subview becomeFirstResponder];
        
        return YES;
        
    }
    
    
    
    if ([subview.subviews count] > 0) {
        
        if ([self setMFMailFieldAsFirstResponder:subview mfMailField:field]){
            
            //Field was found and made first responder in a subview
            
           return YES;
            
        }
        
    }
    
}



//field not found in this view.

return NO;
```

}

but it is showing cursor on a first character of body part. If want cursor after two lines , like

***THIS IS BODY PART FOR MAIL*** and I want cursor after two lines of this message.

I am using    `[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];` for set body part , and I need `isHTML` YES.

Comment: Add two new line characters "\n"

Comment: but where.... ?, i have do it already in body text , but it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
NSString *emailBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<br>Hooray, This is my 2 lines before curser:<br><br>"];
emailbody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"Whatever string or curser you want"];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```